# Table accepts only absolute (pixels) values and not relative (percents) ones

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a website and there is a table with many data rows. So I wanted to make the table scrollable but fixing the table header, so the user knows what the data belongs to.

Now this scroll functionality works well, but the table has collapsed. I am unable to stretch the table to 100% of it's container (as it was before modifying).

The only way that works is setting the width of the table and its colums to an absolute value in pixels. Well as everyone knows, that's extremely unfavorble for mobile design, so it would be great if the table would be normal again with it's relative values...

Here's my code:

```css
$width:1200px;
 .fixed_headers {
  width: $width;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  td: nth-child(1), th: nth-child(1) {
    min-width: calc(0.16 * # {
      $width
    }
    );
  }
  td:nth-child(2),
  th:nth-child(2) {
    min-width: calc(0.42 * # {
      $width
    }
    );
  }
  td:nth-child(3),
  th:nth-child(3) {
    min-width: calc(0.42 * # {
      $width
    }
    );
  }
  thead {
    tr {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: calc(# {
      $width
    }
    - 2px); // border left and right 1px
    height:30vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered fixed-headers">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

As you see, I've set the width of the table to `1200px` but I want this at `100%` to have it responsive.
Do you have an idea how I could solve this?

Example of the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGrzaR?editors=1100

Comment: Why not use media queries with multiple absolute values?

Comment: Because the table should be at 100% of a responsive container. So I would have to make a media query for every pixel which is pretty sensless. And normally it should be possible to use relative values.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Please look up media queries.

Comment: I absolutely know what media queries are. Thanks. But the table is in a modal which spreads to 80% of the viewport at a set max-midth. If the screen is smaller, the modal gets smaller too, so the table also has to get smaller. As the modal is responsive (gets smaller as you resize the screen) the table has to be responsive too. With media queries I can only set a fixed width for a given viewport. So, yes, I would have to make a new query for each pixel! Think about it. You'll notice

Comment: The modal is based on the initial width. Base the query on that width, and you have a modal that goes from 80% to 100 or 70 or however you choose. Also, sounds like the model's responsiveness needs work. It should not be so complicated to work with it.

Comment: The modal works perfectly. Nothing to do there. I think we talk past each other. What I can tell, is that it's not possible to solve this by a merdia query because even with it, I'd need relative values in percent which do not work.  And that's the issue. Even if it was possible with the media query, it would be a very dirty hack. It would bu much cleaner to understand why the table isn't accepting relative values anymore and fixing the issue at it's core. Normal tables also work with percents, so why don't they do it in my case. That's the real issue that should be solved.

Answer (score -2):

An example for your code:

```
<Style>

table {
    width: 100vw;
    max-height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: scroll;
}

th {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30%;
}
td {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
}

</Style>
```

Comment: I don't know why you wrote this code. It has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: @Ollie you should update your original answer instead of adding a new one.

Answer (score -3):

Put the table in a div and set that div to your desired width e.g. 100vw.
Then just set the table to 100%.

Comment: Did you even try it? Or you are just guessing?

Comment: It worked on my machine however I would personally change the code completely.

Comment: Does not work in this case. How would you write the code? I would appreciate your tipps

Comment: Viewport units can be tricky if the majority of the elements that make up your responsive grid are percentages, which base their size on parent/ancestor elements and not the viewport. For example, pretend that this table is a in a main content column, much like StackOverflow's questions and answers are, with a width of 65%. How are you going to handle using viewport units within that 65% width element so it doesn't overflow the element when the viewport unit is larger?

Comment: @hungerstar Don't you have an idea why this is caused?